# Find the probability that both times the "coin eagle" fell out

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The coin is thrown twice. Find the probability that BOTH times the "eagle" fell out, if it is known that during these two throws, the "eagle" fell out at least once.
//"eagle" or "E" means the side of coin without a digit. The side with digit is "D"

My answer is $\frac{1}{3}$ because we have:

E E - that doesn't happen due to "eagle fell out at least once"

D E - ok

E D - ok

D D - we need it

so the answer is $\frac{1}{3}$, but the correct answer is $\frac{3}{4}$. Can you explain me why?

Comment: $\frac13$ is correct. The book probably has a typo.

Comment: I have a problem with understanding what the verb "fall out" means. Could you clarify?

Comment: Hmmm, when we flip the coin, one of the 2 sides falls out. Seems like I used wrong verb due to my bad english :<

Comment: Does "fall out" mean "come up" or the opposite?

Answer (score 1):

How do you "know that the eagle fell out at least once"? Did you happen to see the first throw', which turned out to be an eagle, after which you closed your eyes and didn't see the second throw?  In that case, you "know that the eagle fell out at least once", and the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.

On the other hand, if you had your eyes closed for both throws, and some one tells you that an egale came up at least once, then you also "know that the eagle fell out at least once", but now the probability is $\frac{1}{3}$, exactly following your calculation.

Neither way is it $\frac{3}{4}$ though ... and I can't think of any reqasonable scenario in which you "know that an eagle fell out at least once" that would make it $\frac{3}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are exactly right.

(1/3) is the right answer.